# Invalid left-hand side argument error when concatenating a string with variable in a function

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to concatenate the value in a function with `c` and add 5 each time. However, I keep getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. Does anyone know of a workaround? I am assuming I cannot use the `+` operator as a concatenate and then use it in the `+=`? I'm confused why this isn't working.

```
var c1 = 0;
var c2 = 0;

function(d) {
    d.number; //possible value of 1 or 2
    c + d.number += 5; //isn't this c1 += 5, or c2 += 5?
    "c" + d.number += 5; //also tried this - same error
    console.log(c1);
    console.log(c2);
;}
```

Comment: The left-hand side of any assignment operator must be a simple variable or property reference. What you're trying to do is *possible* in JavaScript but it's not idiomatic. You can make `c1` and `c2` object properties instead of variables and use the `[ ]` operator to construct the property names. Or, make `c` an array instead of two separate variables if you really want to use it as an array.

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy. I rewrote doing that and it is working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case what Pointy said in the comments is not clear, you can "construct" the variable name (as you are trying to do) when it's an object property using the `[ ]` operator.

Here is an example:

```
var cObj = {};
cObj.c1 = 0;
cObj.c2 = 0;

function(d) {
    cObj['c' + d.number] += 5;
    console.log(cObj.c1);
    console.log(cObj.c2);
;}
```

Comment: Yes! That worked great. Thank you for the fast response.

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer when possible. Thanks to Pointy for the team effort.